# How to call another function $('this') relate hover

Tags: jquery

I move some code from hover function to outside be `hover_in()`.
`$(this)` in  function `hover_in()` it doesn't work, how to fix it?
 How should I replace `$('this')` to make it work?

```
$('.a').hover(function(){
    hover_in();
    // var hover_id = $(this).attr('id');
}, function(){});

function hover_in(){
    var hover_id = $(this).attr('id'); // not work
};

<div class='a' id="a1"></div>
<div class='a' id="a2"></div>
<div class='a' id="a3"></div>
...
```

Comment: `$(this)` variable refers to current context object, when you place it separate hover_in(),then it refers to `$(this)` object within that. you can do one thing. pass this object in function call like this `$('.a').hover(function(){  hover_in($(this));    }` then retrieve the same in external function,like this  `function hover_in(var $this){
    var hover_id = $this.attr('id'); // not work
};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you "unwrap" the call to your function it'll work fine:

```
$('.a').hover(hover_in, function() {});
```

The reason is that jQuery will set `this` when it calls the given handler, but in your original version you don't do anything to ensure that its value is passed on to your `hover_in` function when you call it.

If you don't want the event handler to do anything else then there's no advantage in wrapping the whole thing in an anonymous function - quite the opposite, as you've found.

If you want additional stuff to be done in the handler, you could do this:

```
$('.a').hover(function(ev) {
    hover_in.call(this, ev);   // omit 'ev' if it's not needed
    ...
}, ...);
```

which explicitly calls `hover_in` with the right `this` value.

Note also that `$(this).attr('id') === this.id` - the latter is simpler and far more efficient.

Also, if you don't want to pass the second parameter to `.hover`, just use `.mousenter` instead.  Better yet:

```
$('.a').on('mouseenter', hover_in);

function hover_in(){
    var hover_id = this.id;
    ...
};
```

Comment: I add the code like hover_in().call(this); but it shows `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'hover_in().call')`

Comment: @vibskov you shouldn't have braces in there - just `hover_in.call(this)`

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options:

1. pass `this` as an argument to `hover_in`:

   the call would look like: `hover_in(this);`

   the function definition would look like:

   ```
   function hover_in(that) {
       var hover_id = $(that).attr('id'); // not work
   };
   ```
2. To invoke it in a way like `hover_in.call(this);`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value as an argument :

```
$('.a').hover(function(){
    var hover_id = $(this).attr('id');
    hover_in(hover_id);
}, function(){});

function hover_in(id){
    //use id here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/55/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.a').hover(function(){
         //var hover_id = $(this).attr('id');
         // alert(hover_id);
        hover_in($(this));
     });
    function hover_in(div){
        var hover_id = div.attr('id');
        alert(hover_id);    
    }
});
```